# Regex to extract city names (.NET)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, webharvy

Looking for an expression to extract City Names from addresses. Trying to use this expression in WebHarvy which uses the .NET flavor of regex

Example address

```
1234 Savoy Dr Ste 123
New Houston, TX 77036-3320
```

or

```
1234 Savoy Dr Ste 510
Texas, TX 77036-3320
```

So the city name could be single or two words.

The expression I am trying is

```
(\w|\w\s\w)+(?=,\s\w{2})
```

When I am trying this on [RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5Cw%7C%5Cw%5Cs%5Cw%29%2B%28%3F%3D%2C%5Cs%5Cw%7B2%7D%29&i=6200%20Savoy%20Dr%20Ste%20510%0D%0ANew%20Houston%2C%20TX%2077036-3320) it seems to be working fine, but when I am using this in WebHarvy, it only captures the 'n' from the city name New Houston and 'n' from Austin

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try `(\w+(?:[\p{Zs}\t]+\w+)*),\s\w{2}` (or `(\w+(?:[^\S\r\n]+\w+)?),\s\w{2}`) in *WebHarvey*, not at the online tester.

Comment: Works like a charm. Could you please explain this expression so I know what this does? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WebHarvey, if a regex contains a capturing group, its contents are returned. Thus, you do not need a lookahead.

Another point is that you need to match 1 or more word chars, optionally followed with a chunk of whitespaces followed with 1 or more word chars. Your regex contains a repeated capturing group whose contents are re-written upon each iteration and after it finds matching, Group 1 only contains `n`:

[image]

Use

```
(\w+(?:[^\S\r\n]+\w+)?),\s\w{2})
```

See the [regex demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5Cw%2B%28%3F%3A%5B%5Cp%7BZs%7D%5Ct%5D%2B%5Cw%2B%29%2B%29%2C%5Cs%5Cw%7B2%7D&i=6200%20Savoy%20Dr%20Ste%20510%0D%0ANew%20Houston%2C%20TX%2077036-3320)

The `[^\S\r\n]+` part matches any whitespace except CR and LF. You may use `[\p{Zs}\t]+` to match any 1+ *horizontal* whitespaces.

[image]